# 32 bit .net 4 framework is not installled on 64 bit pc

Tags: .net, deployment

I have an application compiled on Win 7 as a 32 bit app. This is done as it must run some 32 bit DLLs that are not available in 64 bit. When I deploy this to a win 32 bit machine everything is ok. But when I deploy to a 64 bit machine (win 7/8) the installer does not install the 32 bit .net 4 prerequisite - only the 64 bit.

Thus the app will not run and the 32 bit .net framework has to be manually downloaded and installed before the installation of my app can proceed - which is a pain for users

How can I get the 32 bit .net4 framework installed automatically and silently in my deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced Installer, to make setup file for your application, and there is option for .net framework to get it installed silent if it is missing on app installation :)